# Should my pool pump be hard-wired or plugged into an oulet?

Tags: electrical-panel, circuit-breaker, heater, pool

I have pool heat pump plugged to 30A outlet, with 10#

my questions :

1. following instructions on the plate, is it ok to leave this pump plugged to this 30A outlet (connected to 30A breaker) I mean is it safe or I must use 20A circuit, breaker 20A + 12# wire till the pump ( disctance 37' )
   I don't have enoug space on my panel, so can I remove this 30A breaker and replace it with 20A ? (wiring as well )
2. I heard that if the heater is hard wired is better than outlet because of wattage loss, is it the only reason or is it safer also ?

Thanks

[image: pool heat pump]

Comment: "*10#*"  # is not a descriptor for wire that i am familiar with.  Do you mean AWG ( gauge ) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/American_wire_gauge

Comment: Most electricians do call 10awg #10.

Comment: _Number_ ten (#10) as opposed to ten _pound_ (10#).

Comment: There must be something in the water today.  several snippy comments JW was in a mood this morning and now isherwood.  LOL...just teasing.

Comment: Number 10 means the government...

Comment: @SolarMike That took me a minute...because I'm closer to 1600 Pennsylvania

Comment: @manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact yes - the issue of using jargon when it is like a secret code to the uninitiated. And a source of error when things can be ambiguous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The max rating is 25a so replacing the 30 amp breaker with a 20 will probably work. Most jurisdictions don’t allow a plug for a disconnect it would be proper to have a standard 30 or 60 amp rated disconnect , if it Tripp’s the 20 amp on start up you can use a larger breaker but because the MFG states max 25 that’s the max. You can always use larger wire so that is fine.

Comment: "most jurisdictions won't allow a plug for a disconnect"  Is that because it could just be plugged back in without the maintenance person knowing it?

Comment: For a permanent install a disconnect is usually required corded devices are considered portable.

Comment: Yeah, the limitation is on using flexible cords to connect permanent equipment, not in using a socket as a DC.  Too use a cord it has to qualify for one of the excuses in 400.6-8.